# How to push JSON data to an array with duplicate values in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, duplicates, push

I have to return all the data which is present in the table_name without any removal of duplicate values, till the console i can see all the records from db , once it is pushed to an array1 then my repeated records got disappeared.
I want to return all the records.

```
 db.query('SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name', function(err, data) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     var array = [],
     array1 = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
         if (array[data.rows[i].name]) continue;
             array[data.rows[i].name] = true;
             console.log(array[data.rows[i].name])// till here
             array1 .push(data.rows[i])

     }
         return res.status(200).send(array1 );
});
```

Comment: Change the entire function below the `err` handler to `return data.rows`.

Comment: My bad!! @CertainPerformance:) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using multiple arrays, hope this will help you

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name', function(err, data) {
         if (err) return next(err);
         var array = [],
         array1 = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
             if (array[data.rows[i].name]) continue;
                 array[data.rows[i].name] = true;
                 array1 .push(data.rows)
         }
             return res.status(200).send(array1 );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding properties to the `array` variable in the first line of the loop, using the `name` property from `data`. If some other row exists with the same name, the item won't be added.